# Show that $\sum_0^{\infty}\frac{z^{2^n}}{z^{2^{n+1}}-1}$ converges to $\frac{z}{z-1}$ or $\frac{-1}{1-z}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, summation

How do we show that the sum below converges to $\frac{z}{z-1}$ if $|z|<1$ and $\frac{-1}{1-z}$ if $|z|>1$?

$$\sum_0^{\infty}\frac{z^{2^n}}{z^{2^{n+1}}-1}=\frac{z}{z^2-1}+\frac{z^2}{z^4-1}+\frac{z^4}{z^8-1}+...$$

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note

\begin{align}\frac{z^{2^n}}{z^{2^{n+1}}-1} &= \frac{z^{2^n}(z^{2^n}-1)}{(z^{2^n}-1)(z^{2^{n+1}}-1)} = \frac{z^{2^{n+1}}-z^{2^n}}{(z^{2^n}-1)(z^{2^{n+1}}-1)} \\
&= \frac{(z^{2^{n+1}}-1) - (z^{2^n}-1)}{(z^{2^n}-1)(z^{2^{n+1}}-1)}\\
& = \frac{1}{z^{2^n} - 1} - \frac{1}{z^{2^{n+1}}-1}.
\end{align}

So for every positive integer $N$,

$$\sum_{n = 0}^N \frac{z^{2^n}}{z^{2^{n+1}}-1} = \frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{z^{2^{N+1}}-1}.\tag{*}$$

by telescoping. Now evaluate the limit as $N\to \infty$ of the right-hand side (*) depending on the cases $|z| < 1$ and $|z| > 1$.

Comment: What you wrote makes complete sense up to the telescoping line (*) - I am a little unfamiliar with this topic, so would you mind elaborating on it? Thanks!

Comment: Sure. If you write out the terms, everything cancels except for $\frac{1}{z-1}$ and $\frac{1}{z^{2^{N+1}}-1}$. Try it out and you'll see. :)