# How can we show that $\frac{x}{1-x} = \sum \frac{x^{2^n}}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}$ for $0<x<1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> How can we show that $\frac{x}{1-x} = \sum \frac{x^{2^n}}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}$

I've been stuck on this question. I've tried using the geometric series but to no avail.

Comment: @Phicar I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: You must specify which values of n are used in the summation.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1502741/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/788932/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1628569/42969.

Answer (score 3):

Here we start like this :
\begin{align*}
s(x)& :=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2^n}}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}\\
& =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2^n}+x^{2^{n+1}}-x^{2^{n+1}}}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}\\
& =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^{2^n}}{1-x^{2^n}}-\frac{x^{2^{n+1}}}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}\right)\\
& =\frac{x}{1-x}.
\end{align*}